# Scrape image from amazon with python 3 and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape the main image from a product page of amazon.
I stored the ASIN into a list and i build every single product page with a for loop.
i'm trying to scrape the images but i can't. I try with this code:

```
#declare a session object
session = HTMLSession()

#ignore warnings
if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

urls = ['https://www.amazon.it/gp/bestsellers/apparel/', 'https://www.amazon.it/gp/bestsellers/electronics/', 'https://www.amazon.it/gp/bestsellers/books/']
asins = []
for url in urls:
    content = requests.get(url).content
    decoded_content = content.decode()
    asins = re.findall(r'/[^/]+/dp/([^\"?]+)', decoded_content)

#The ASIN Number will be between the dp/ and another /

for asin in asins:
    site = 'https://www.amazon.it/'
    start = 'dp/'
    end = '/'
    url = site + start + asin + end
    resp1 = requests.get(url).content

    soup = bsoup(resp1, "html.parser")
    body = soup.find("body")
    imgtag = soup.find("img", {"id":"landingImage"})
    imageurl = dict(imgtag.attrs)["src"]
    resp2 = request.urlopen(imaegurl)
```

Comment: When I go to the first page gathered by the findall (https://www.amazon.it/dp/8891822582/), I don't see any landingImage, id'd items. Are you looking for this picture? [link](https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51rhrFelgeL._SY264_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_.jpg). The tag I see is: class="a-dynamic-image image-stretch-vertical frontImage" id = "imgBlkFront". I am able to see it in a find_all loop through the img items. May be best to gather into a list and use re again to trim down. It will be slower, but more stable as Amz doesn't love scraping.

Comment: Yes, that was the image i'm searching to scraping.
But how have you done?

Can you post the code?

Comment: But i obtain always the same image, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the images are loaded dinamically; inspecting the page, and thanks to the *BeautifulSoup* [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), I was able to scrape all the images needed, given a product.

## Take the page of a given link

I have a class in which store data, so I save the page information in the instance...

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def take_page(self, url_page):
    req = urllib.request.Request(
        url_page,
        data=None
    )
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    page = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    self.page = page
```

## Scrape images

The following simple method will return the first image, in the smallest size

```
import json

def take_image(self):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.page, 'html.parser')
    img_div = soup.find(id="imgTagWrapperId")

    imgs_str = img_div.img.get('data-a-dynamic-image')  # a string in Json format

    # convert to a dictionary
    imgs_dict = json.loads(imgs_str)
    #each key in the dictionary is a link of an image, and the value shows the size (print all the dictionay to inspect)
    num_element = 0 
    first_link = list(imgs_dict.keys())[num_element]
    return first_link
```

So, you can apply these methods to your needs, I think that this is all you need to improve your code.

Answer (score -1):

Code example to see 'all' of the img's on the page

```
for asin in asins:
    site = 'https://www.amazon.it/'
    start = 'dp/'
    end = '/'
    url = site + start + asin + end
    print(url)
    resp1 = requests.get(url).content


    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp1, "html.parser")
    for i in soup.find_all("img"):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

Proper way of doing this is via Amazon Affiliate API account, but if you don't have one. Here's recent code using ScraperAPI `lxml` with `cssselect` and `PIL`

Key parts are `dom.cssselect` to get image from its element on the page, a request proxy and using PIL to save images properly. Tested on books, other pages will use a higher up element

```
def save_img(url, name):
    response = requests.get(PROXY + url, stream=True)
    out_path = f'static/bookimg/{name}.jpg'
    try:
        i = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
        i.save(out_path)
    except (UnidentifiedImageError, OSError) as e:
        print(e)


def get_img_by_asin(asin, save_name):
    url = PROXY + f'https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/{asin}/'
    print(url)
    html = requests.get(url).content
    dom = fromstring(html)
    try:
        img = dom.cssselect("#ebooks-img-canvas img")[-1]
        save_img(img.get('src'), save_name)
    except IndexError:
        print('No image or bad response')
```

https://gist.github.com/fmalina/03c84100e84ecc2ae2cd23d60e11959e